# The structure of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

This is a sentence from **Beyond Good and Evil**:

> The question is, how far an opinion is life-furthering, life-
>   preserving, species-preserving, perhaps species-rearing, and we are fundamentally inclined to maintain that the falsest opinions (to which
>   the synthetic judgments a priori belong), are the most indispensable
>   to us, that without a recognition of logical fictions, without a
>   comparison of reality with the purely IMAGINED world of the absolute
>   and immutable, without a constant counterfeiting of the world by means
>   of numbers, man could not live—that the renunciation of false opinions
>   would be a renunciation of life, a negation of life.

I understood the meaning of sentence, but the structure of sentence is difficult to understand. 
Please explain.

Comment: If you understand the meaning, in what capacity do you want to understand the structure? Theory about sentence structure in English is fairly limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s all just lists.

The author states "the question is" and then poses a list of two questions (one is misformed in the original posting).

Each question is a fully formed sentence.

The first question asks about a list of "X-preserving" actions.

The second question "are we inclined to maintain...." is followed by a list of "that" clauses, and the second contains a list of "without" phrases.

So while the author states "the question is", I count 9 different questions.

> The question is:
>
> (Q1) "how far an opinion is
>
> - life-furthering,
> - life- preserving,
> - species-preserving,
> - perhaps species-rearing,"
>
> and
>
> (Q2) "<s>we are</s>are we fundamentally inclined to maintain
>
> - that the falsest opinions (to which the synthetic judgments a priori belong), are the most indispensable to us,
> - that (
> - - without a recognition of logical fictions,
> - - without a comparison of reality with the purely IMAGINED world of the absolute and immutable,
> - - without a constant counterfeiting of the world by means of numbers, ) man could not live
> - that the renunciation of false opinions would be a renunciation of life, a negation of life."